# SwiftUI updating view with shared viewModel binding

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

I have a view (MainView) containing a model (ConfigModel), declared as a StateObject. The ConfigModel adheres to the ObservableObject protocol and @Published a struct (Config).

The MainView contains a List with multiple subviews. Each subview takes the ConfigModel as a binding argument. Now I would like SubView1 to get updated if SubView2 changes a variable inside Config.

This does not work. Should I use EnvironmentObject? If so why, and why does sharing the ConfigModel between multiple views not work?

```
struct MainView: View {
// own model
@StateObject var viewModel: ConfigModel

// layout
var body: some View {

    List {
        // subview1
        SubView1(config: $viewModel.model.config)
        
        // subview2
        SubView2(config: $viewModel.model.config)
    }
}
}
```

ViewModel

```
class ConfigModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var model: Model() 
}
```

Example of SubView

```
struct SubView1: View {
@StateObject var viewModel: SubViewModel

init(configModel: Binding<ConfigModel>) {
    _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: SubViewModel(configModel: configModel))
}

var body: some View {
    Text("Total time: \(viewModel.totalTimeString())")
}
}
```

SubviewModel

```
class SubViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Binding var configModel: ConfigModel

init(configModel: Binding<ConfigModel>) {
    self._configModel = configModel
}
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI wrappers with the exception of `@Published` in an `ObservableObject` do not work in a `class`. You can't chain `ObservableObject`s and expect to get updates for the changes in the `class`. You can subscribe using `.sink` but you can't use a wrapper.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Do you know where I can find an example of this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=.sink%20swiftui